# Yocto how do you add meta-networking layer to your config?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I am trying to look at the https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/dunfell/layers/ and add `dhcp` and `dnsmasq` to my image.
My local.conf has the following line:
`CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL_append = " dhcpcd dnsmasq openssh iptables"`

However, the bitbake fails with error `ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'dhcpcd'`
Layer index: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/dunfell/recipes/?q=dhcp ; shows multiple entries including one in `openembedded-core` which I believe is the `meta` default layer.
In my pc, `poky/meta` shows:

```
classes
conf
COPYING.MIT
files
lib
recipes-bsp
recipes-connectivity
recipes-core
recipes-devtools
recipes-extended
recipes-gnome
recipes-graphics
recipes-kernel
recipes-multimedia
recipes-rt
recipes-sato
recipes-support
recipes.txt
site
```

`Recipes-connectivity` lists:

```
avahi
bind
bluez5
connman
dhcp
inetutils
iproute2
iw
libnss-mdns
libpcap
mobile-broadband-provider-info
neard
nfs-utils
ofono
openssh
openssl
ppp
ppp-dialin
resolvconf
socat
ssh-pregen-hostkeys
wpa-supplicant
```

I found the following files of importance:

```
dhcp/files/dhcpd.conf
dhcp/dhcp.inc
dhcp/dhcp_4.4.2.bb
```

Surprisingly `dhcp-client` in place of `dhcpcd` seems to work which makes no sense as there is no recipe file name with `dhcp-server_...bb`
Looks like my yocto should find the dhcp. So why is it failing?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the good tools, `dhcpd` is indeed present in `openembedded-core`, but this meta is not the default one (`poky/meta`) !

This `meta-networking` is from the parent meta `meta-openembedded`.

You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/dunfell) (dunfell branch).

The recipe is in [`meta-networking/recipes-connectivity/dhcpcd`](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/dunfell/meta-networking/recipes-connectivity/dhcpcd).

You can see it on the recipe description on [Openembedded Layer index](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/124750/)

You need to clone this meta and add it your setup (`gbitbake-layers` or manually)

---

You can use `bitbake-layers` to add/remove/create layers.

To add a layer:

```
bitbake-layers add-layer <path>
```

To show layers used:

```
bitbake-layers show-layers
```

You will find more help in the [Yocto development manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/layers.html#managing-layers)

---

You can also modify manually your `<builddir>/conf/bblayers.conf` file to add the path of your layer you want to add.

Comment: I understand that but my issue here is I'm not able to make out which layer provides what. I thought default recipes are present in yocto poky level for all the basic stuff like networking, bash, etc. How do I know which layer to choose and what's available as default?

Comment: @preetamI I overlooked the real question this morning, hopefully it's the weekend. I have updated my answer to correctly answer you.